# Send Mail via iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i want to send a Mail in my app with an .PHP file as Attachment:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:@""];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self getScriptPath]];
    NSString *fileName = @"upload.php";
    [mailViewController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/html" fileName:fileName];
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [mailViewController release];
}
else 
    NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state.");
```

The Mail is being sent, but without the attachment!...

Comment: What does it say if you log myData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your `[self getScriptPath]` method return an invalid path, or a path to a non-existing file, and thus `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:...]` probably return `nil`.

You should use a breakpoint or NSLog to check the value returned by `getScriptPath` and fix it accordingly.

For example if you embedded the `"upload.php"` file in your application (you added it in your Xcode project, along with the other resources of your application), you should use this to get the valid path of your script file in your bundle:

```
-(NSString*)getScriptPath
{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"upload" ofType:@"php"];
}
```

See the [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW8) documentation for more info.

Comment: yee i think so...but my method returns the right path! My upload.php file i dragged into Xcode! So is it in the Documents directory?!

Comment: No. If you dragged your `upload.php` file into Xcode to include it in your project, the file will be included inside the bundle of your application. The Documents directory is where you put file that the user create on the fly when using your application; the file embedded in your application when you compile it are in the application bundle itself. Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"upload" ofType:@"php"]` instead to get the right path for your `"upload.php"` resource file in your application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to attach image file.

```
UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loveCoding.png"];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(emailImage, 1) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"loveCocoa.png"];
```

To attach file

```
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.txt",sGame.userName];
    NSString *fullFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *emailFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Report.txt",sGame.userName];

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullFilePath];

    [email addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:emailFileName];
```

Comment: @chrizstone you need to specify fullPath

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your NSData is not loading correctly.  Check your path from getScriptPath